# JQuery validation for decimal numbers fails for the French language

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins

I have a text input with a decimal value that represents a dollar amount in an ASP.NET MVC web app. This is fine for the English language, but when I switch to French, the client side validation fails because it does not recognize the amount as a number (e.g. 190.00), in French, this would be 190,00. In the app we would like to force the display for currency to be in English regardless of the selected language.I have looked into the various localization files, but those are just used to format the error messages.

Is a way to override the setting that makes decimal values in English get caught as an error to the JQuery validate library?

Here is the DOM output from the razor code:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Montant must be a number."
 data-val-regex="Entrez une valeur supérieure à 0" data-val-regex-pattern="^0*[1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?|0+\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*$"
data-val-required="The Montant field is required."   id="TransactionDetails_BillingAmount" name="TransactionDetails.BillingAmount"     type="text" value="190.00"
aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"
class="valid" aria-describedby="TransactionDetails_BillingAmount-error">
```

Comment: pls show us some code

Comment: try this in regex pattern `^0*[1-9][0-9]*(\,[0-9]+)?\,[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*$`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I should have mentioned that the "." separator is not being recognized in French. I don't really want to allow the comma as a separator, just for the French to recognize the period as a valid separator.

Comment: `data-val-number` will be used by `jquery.validate.js` to validate the number based on a `.` (dot) decimal separator so you regex is pointless. You can use using [jquery.globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) or add your own rule to override the default in `jquery.validate.js`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value on change of the input box for french langugae,replace , with dot(.) and perform the validation with jquery as you are doing for english language.

Dont know if this might help you... but i did the same when i encountered the same problem.